# How to pass parameters to a view in Rails, e. g. for a search page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Normally in rails, you pass parameters to views pretty explicitly, by using code like `@user = User.find(params[:id])`.  And then forms can infer their status by using the resulting object, such as `form_for @user do ... end`.

I'm building a search page that operates on the index.  To minimize code writing & duplication between controllers, I'm using the has_scope gem.

So my controller looks like `def show @users = apply_scopes(User); end`  How can I pass the various scopes being applied into the view so I can re-use them in the search fields?  My first thought is to make params a helper method, but...  that's a code smell.  A pretty big one, I'm told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the README](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope):

> You can retrieve all the scopes applied in one action with `current_scopes` method.

Comment: Yeah, they could do a better job of highlighting it, like showing it in an example - it's such a common thing to do.